# Filtering Query Nested Data (Dataset and Association)

Tags: dataset, data-structures, filtering, associations, query

I am trying to filter a nested Dataset.

I have some data that looks like this (curated for this example):

```
h = Dataset@{<|"basicData" -> <|"ID" -> "1008", 
  "dateMMa" -> {2014, 10, 8, 0, 0, 0.`}|>, 
"away" -> <|"City" -> "montréal"|>, 
"home" -> <|"City" -> "toronto"|>|>, <|"basicData" -> <|"ID" -> 
   "1009", "dateMMa" -> {2014, 10, 8, 1, 0, 0.`}|>, 
"away" -> <|"City" -> "philadelphia"|>, 
"home" -> <|"City" -> "boston"|>|>}
```

I would like to filter this on "dateMMA" for anything earlier than {2014, 10, 8, 1, 0, 0.`} (October 8th 2014).  This should yield only one item:

```
<|"basicData" -> <|"ID" -> "1008",  "dateMMa" -> {2014, 10, 8, 0, 0, 0.`}|>,  "away" -> <|"City" -> "montréal"|>,  "home" -> <|"City" -> "toronto"|>|>
```

This does not work:

```
h[[All, "basicData"]][Select[AbsoluteTime@#dateMMa > AbsoluteTime[{2014, 10, 8, 1, 0, 0.`}] &]]
```

Nor does this:

```
h[All, "basicData", Select[AbsoluteTime@#dateMMa > AbsoluteTime[{2014, 10, 8, 1, 0, 0.`}] &]]
```

Nor does this:

```
h[Select[AbsoluteTime@#dateMMa > AbsoluteTime[{2014, 10, 8, 1, 0, 0.`}] &]]
```

Is this type of filter/query possible?

Would there be a better way to structure this Dataset to achieve this goal?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following query will return the desired result:

```
h[Select[AbsoluteTime@#["basicData", "dateMMa"] < AbsoluteTime@{2014,10,8,1,0,0} &]]

(* {<|"basicData" -> <|"ID" -> "1008", "dateMMa" -> {2014, 10, 8, 0, 0, 0.}|>, ... |> *)
```

The vital construction in this solution is `#["basicData", "dateMMa"]`.  It references the nested key `dateMMa` within the key `basicData`.

Incidentally, note that `<` was used instead of `>` for the date comparison as the text of the question requests anything earlier than the cutoff date.

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Thank you. The #[key1, key2] notation is new to me.

Comment: Indeed, after reading this useful answer, I haven't found a reference for this syntax in the documentation. Maybe it exists, but it's likely not easy to find.

Comment: In fact each # in the Select is an association, so this is not a special syntax. Useful post anyway !