# Select query with named slot lookups?

Tags: dataset, associations, query

Given this `Dataset` fragment (copy-paste friendly version at bottom)

[image]

Can this query be simplified by referencing named slots directly in the `Select` logic?

```
data[All, Values /* Thread][All, All, Apply@Join][All, Select[#VisitStartTime <= #"WEBCAM_TIME" <= #VisitEndTime &]]
```

[image]

Although functional, limitations include: (1) Creates intermediate Datasets; (2) threads `VisitStartTime` and `VisitEndTime`, which must then be dropped; (3) `Values` removes the `Key` "Morae/..." which must then be reinstered in each row; (4) overall complexity makes it difficult to modify to similar datasets.

An approach based on named slot syntax shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69045/filtering-query-nested-data-dataset-and-association/69059#69059) by WReach looks applicable, but the naive version fails:

```
data[All, {"Morae/Manual/Emr/Coder1Data" -> 
   Select[#["Master", "VisitStartTime"] <=  #"WEBCAM_TIME" <= #[
       "Master", "VisitEndTime"] &]}]
```

[image]

Even though it is possible to reference the slots in the other branch like this:

```
data[All, {"Morae/Manual/Emr/Coder1Data" -> {#["Master", 
      "VisitStartTime"], #["Master", "VisitEndTime"]} &}]
```

[image]

Is it possible to combine these path-lookup methods?

**INPUT DATA**

```
data = <|"Q001" -> <|"Morae/Manual/Emr/Coder1Data" -> {<|"WEBCAM_TIME" -> 
       TimeObject[{0, 12, 9.4}], 
      "TASK" -> "F1"|>, <|"WEBCAM_TIME" -> TimeObject[{0, 12, 10.1}], 
      "TASK" -> "F1"|>, <|"WEBCAM_TIME" -> TimeObject[{0, 12, 13.1}], 
      "TASK" -> "F1"|>, <|"WEBCAM_TIME" -> TimeObject[{0, 12, 27.9}], 
      "TASK" -> "F1"|>}, 
   "Master" -> <|"VisitStartTime" -> TimeObject[{0, 12, 15.}], 
     "VisitEndTime" -> TimeObject[{0, 38, 49.}]|>|>, 
 "Q002" -> <|"Morae/Manual/Emr/Coder1Data" -> {<|"WEBCAM_TIME" -> 
       TimeObject[{0, 0, 1.9}], 
      "TASK" -> "F25"|>, <|"WEBCAM_TIME" -> TimeObject[{0, 0, 3.5}], 
      "TASK" -> "F25"|>, <|"WEBCAM_TIME" -> TimeObject[{0, 0, 9.7}], 
      "TASK" -> "F25"|>, <|"WEBCAM_TIME" -> TimeObject[{0, 0, 10.8}], 
      "TASK" -> "F25"|>}, 
   "Master" -> <|"VisitStartTime" -> TimeObject[{0, 13, 0.}], 
     "VisitEndTime" -> TimeObject[{0, 22, 27.}]|>|>|> //Dataset
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a complication that prevents us from using a single `Select` and named slots: we need to form a cross-product of the data and master elements.  Even so, the query can be simplified somewhat:

```
data[All
, Join @@@ Tuples[{#"Morae/Manual/Emr/Coder1Data", {#Master}}] & /*
    Select[#VisitStartTime <= #"WEBCAM_TIME" <= #VisitEndTime &]
]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

The `Join@@@Tuples` construction forms the cross-product and collapses each pair of associations into a single association.  That leaves us in a position to apply the `Select`.

---

**Side note: A limitation in `JoinAcross`**

One might think to use `JoinAcross` to form the cross-product.  Unfortunately, it does not handle a vacuous join condition properly:

```
JoinAcross[{<|a->1|>, <|a->2|>}, {<|b->10|>}, {}]
(* {} *)
```

Since `JoinAcross` is advertised as the *Mathematica* equivalent of a relational join, I would have expected the result to be the same as this:

```
Join @@@ Tuples[{{<|a -> 1|>, <|a -> 2|>}, {<|b -> 10|>}}]
(* {<|a -> 1, b -> 10|>, <|a -> 2, b -> 10|>} *)
```

But it is not.  I am sorely tempted to call this a bug, but let's go with "limitation" for now :)

---

**Update**

If the master data is not required in the output (as mentioned in a comment), things can made simpler because we can eliminate the explicit cross-product.  We start by defining a helper function that encapsulates the filtering condition:

```
filter[data_, master_] :=
  Select[data, master["VisitStartTime"] <= #"WEBCAM_TIME" <= master["VisitEndTime"]&]
```

This enables us to use a much simpler query:

```
data[All
, <| "Morae/Manual/Emr/Coder1Data" -> (filter[#"Morae/Manual/Emr/Coder1Data", #Master]&) |>
]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

If desired, the master data can also be retained as a separate key like this:

```
data[All
, <| "Morae/Manual/Emr/Coder1Data" -> (filter[#"Morae/Manual/Emr/Coder1Data", #Master]&)
   , "Master" -> "Master"
  |>
]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Comment: Thanks again for the analysis. However, doesn't address limitations (2) and (3), namely `VisitStartTime` and `VisitEndTime` are only for use in the `Select` logic and should *not* appear in the output, and desired format is `<|"Q001" -> {"Morae/Manual/Emr/Coder1Data" -> ...}, ...|>`, ie, with `Morae...` key included. Ideally (2) and (3) should not be post-processing steps.

Comment: @alancalvitti Ah yes, my misunderstanding.  Does my update help?

Comment: Why does it only return a single row in `Q001` (compare to the output in my Q)

Comment: @alancalvitti If I run your query against the exhibited input data, I get the same result as my query: the single entry for 00:12:27.9.  That is correct since it is the only one between 00:12:15 and 00:38:49.  Perhaps your screenshot was taken after using different data?

Comment: You're right, I was A/B'ing to my original input data. Nice solution here, thanks.